# Custom .htaccess Rewrites for individual files

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am making a music player that can use GET variables to select the play list, i would like to know how to use a single .htaccess file to keep my current .htaccess and only for **music.php** (or Ducke.Co/music) use a different rewrite to change `music?f=PLAYLISTNAME` to `music/PLAYLISTNAME`.

My current .htaccess is as follows:

```
ErrorDocument 500 /DuckeCo/ErrorPages/500
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: You don't need separate `.htaccess` files, just an extra `RewriteRule`. Put it above the current one, and use [the `[L]` flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l), and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right under the `RewriteBase /` line, add:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+music\?f=([^[&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /music/%1? [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^music/(.+)$ /music?f=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: This sorta works, it loads the page with the Get variable, but now (Only on the page with the get variable) no css or js loads.

Comment: @Ducky that's probably because you have relative links in your page's content. The browser uses the wrong base URL when it thinks there's subdirectories in the URL it just requested (e.g. `/music/something` vs `/music?f=something`). Either change your links to absolute URL's (by adding a leading `/`) or add a relative URL base to the header of your pages: `<base href="/" />`